# Generate summary for each row based on column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i have data frame like this.

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {'Sub1':['A','B','C','D','E'],
            'Sub2':['F','G','H','I','J'],
            'Sub3':['K','L','M','N','O'],
    'S_score1': [1, 0, 0, 6,0], 
    'S_score2': [0, 1, 0, 6,0], 
    'S_score3': [0, 1, 0, 6,0], 
    }

df2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Sub1','Sub2','Sub3','S_score1', 'S_score2', 'S_score3'])
```

**Have data frame**

[image: have]

i wants to check score columns and check if the score is greater than 1 then take the respective subject in text.

**Wanted Output:**

[image: wanted output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, separate out the grade columns from the one hot columns.

```
u = df2.filter(like='Sub')
v = df2.filter(like='S_score').astype(bool)
```

Next, aggregate letter grades by multiplication, and set column values.

```
r = (u.mul(v.values)
      .agg(','.join, axis=1)
      .str.strip(',')
      .str.replace(',{2,}', ','))
df2['s_text'] = np.where(r.str.len() > 0, 'You scored ' + r, 'N/A')    
df2

  Sub1 Sub2 Sub3  S_score1  S_score2  S_score3            s_text
0    A    F    K         1         0         0      You scored A
1    B    G    L         0         1         1    You scored G,L
2    C    H    M         0         0         0               N/A
3    D    I    N         6         6         6  You scored D,I,N
4    E    J    O         0         0         0               N/A
```

---

To make the last separator different, you will need a custom function.

```
def join(lst):
    lst = lst[lst != '']
    if len(lst) > 1:
        return 'You scored ' + ', '.join(lst[:-1]) + ' and ' + lst[-1] 
    elif len(lst) > 0:
        return 'You scored ' + ', '.join(lst)
    return 'N/A'

df2['s_text'] = u.mul(v.values).agg(join, axis=1)
df2

  Sub1 Sub2 Sub3  S_score1  S_score2  S_score3                 s_text
0    A    F    K         1         0         0           You scored A
1    B    G    L         0         1         1     You scored G and L
2    C    H    M         0         0         0                    N/A
3    D    I    N         6         6         6  You scored D, I and N
4    E    J    O         0         0         0                    N/A
```

Comment: May still need lambda just protect output like 'A,,B'

Comment: @coldspeed thanks for this. if i wanted to insert and in between the text how to do that? like You Scored G, and L, You Score D, I and N like this.

Comment: @KumarAK I have incorporated your request into my answer. Any further requests will need to go into a new question. Thanks!

Comment: @coldspeed hey i have posted another question regarding this can you please look into that.

Answer (score 2):

Doing with `join` after multiple

```
s=(df2.filter(like='Sub')*df2.filter(like='S_').ge(1).values).apply( lambda x : ','.join([y for y in x if y is not '']),axis=1)
s
Out[324]: 
0        A
1      G,L
2         
3    D,I,N
4         
dtype: object
```

Then chain with np.where

```
np.where(s=='','You do not have score','You have'+s)
Out[326]: 
array(['You haveA', 'You haveG,L', 'You do not have score',
       'You haveD,I,N', 'You do not have score'], dtype=object)
```

---

```
#Assign it back 

df2['s_txt']=np.where(s=='','You do not have score','You have'+s)
df2
Out[328]: 
  Sub1 Sub2          ...           S_score3                  s_txt
0    A    F          ...                  0              You haveA
1    B    G          ...                  1            You haveG,L
2    C    H          ...                  0  You do not have score
3    D    I          ...                  6          You haveD,I,N
4    E    J          ...                  0  You do not have score
[5 rows x 7 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions consists of the following steps:

1. Define a function generating the output text for a source row.
   This function should join source columns filtered for not null.
2. Generate `subs` table containing `Sub1`, `Sub2` and `Sub3`.
3. Generate `msk` (mask) table containing `S_score...` columns and
   change column names to `Sub1`, `Sub2` and `Sub3`.
4. Compute `subs.where(msk)` and apply the above function to each row.
   Note that for *False* elements in mask, the respective output element
   is *None*, so the function applied will not include it in join.

So the whole script can look like below:

```
def txt(x):
    tbl = list(filter(lambda elem: not pd.isnull(elem), x))
    if len(tbl) > 0:
        return 'You have scored on ' + ', '.join(tbl)
    else:
        return 'You have not scored any subject'

subs = df.loc[:, :'Sub3']
msk = df.loc[:, 'S_score1':] > 0
msk.columns = ['Sub1', 'Sub2', 'Sub3']
df['s_text'] = subs.where(msk).apply(txt, axis=1)
```