# row wise check and generate text with numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame like this

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {'ID': [101,101,102,101,102],
            'Loc':['IN','IN','NY','IN','NY'],
            'Sub1':['A','B','C','D','E'],
            'Sub2':['F','G','H','I','J'],
            'Sub3':['K','L','M','N','O'],
        'S_score1': [1, 0, 0, 6,0], 
        'S_score2': [0, 1, 0, 6,0], 
        'S_score3': [0, 1, 0, 6,0], 
        }

df2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['ID','Loc','Sub1','Sub2','Sub3','S_score1', 'S_score2', 'S_score3'])
```

Have dataset:

[image: have]

i wants to check score columns and check if the score is greater than 1 then take the respective subject and count in text.

Wanted Output:

[image: wanted output]

it is similar to below question but i am unable to get the count as we have extra extra columns and also needs to get the count requirement is different.

[row wise values check and generate text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53820394/row-wise-values-check-and-generate-text)

Comment: Just modified your sub columns before doing the method we provided in your previous question

Comment: `u = df2.filter(like='Sub');
v = df2.filter(like='S_score').astype(str);
v.columns=u.columns;
u=u+'('+v+')'
` all other is same

Comment: this is the error i am getting can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str' as we have extra columns.are you mentioning the one coldspeed code only right?

Comment: u = df2.filter(like='Sub');  v= df2.filter(like='S_score').astype(bool);s = df2.filter(like='S_score').astype(str); s.columns=u.columns; u=u+'('+s+')'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that what I write as "df" means what you wrote as "df2".

```
df['AuxIndex'] = [i for i in range(len(df))]


def ScoreText(index):

    Sub1 = df['Sub1'][index]
    Sub2 = df['Sub2'][index]
    Sub3 = df['Sub3'][index]

    Score1 = df['S_score1'][index]
    Score2 = df['S_score2'][index]
    Score3 = df['S_score3'][index]

    if(Score1 + Score2 + Score3 == 0):

        return 'You have not scored'

    else:

        scoreText = 'You have scored on '+ '{x}{y}{z}'.format(x = ' {}({})'.format(Sub1,Score1) if Score1 > 0 else '',
                                                              y = ' {}({})'.format(Sub2,Score2) if Score2 > 0 else '',
                                                              z = ' {}({})'.format(Sub3,Score3) if Score3 > 0 else '' )

    return scoreText



df['S_Text'] = df['AuxIndex'].map(lambda i: ScoreText(i))

df.drop(columns = 'AuxIndex')
```

[image]

Let me know if that helps :)